# storing text file data in MySql with timestamp in quotes " " and some missing data values

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am reading data from a text file and storing it in MySql database. the data format in the text file is

```
"sd","modu","datfil","244","de3000.Std.27","CPU:KC.EBM1_16.02.18.cd","13","ffm"
"TIMESTAMP","RNO","tem","t_vel","tem_acc","velc","sd","sd_ds_as"
"","","mp","mp","mp","mp","mp","mp"
"2009-02-25 14:28:36.76",missing RNO,8.277527,0.68,0.15,0.42,762.0303,4.6801
"2009-02-25 14:28:36.8",missing RNO,8.24408,0.7,0.03,0.3,761.878,4.682412
"2009-02-25 14:29:36.88",2,8.277527,0.55,0.09,0.31,762.0018,4.680709
"2009-02-25 14:30:36.92",3,8.277527,0.47,0.2,0.31,761.8914,4.684526
"2009-02-25 14:48:36.96",4,8.277527,0.46,0.14,0.28,761.9133,4.692356
"2009-02-25 14:58:37",5,8.210632,0.42,0.09,0.35,761.9025,4.696963
"2009-02-25 14:58:37.08",6,8.277527,0.51,0.19,0.27,761.8416,4.69718
"2009-02-25 14:58:37.12",7,8.277527,0.36,0.23,0.33,761.7534,4.701172
"2009-02-25 14:58:37.16",8,8.24408,0.44,0.08,0.5,761.8087,4.700504
```

the problem is that timestamp is enclosed in "" and also some data value includes milisecond. to address this issue I make following code

```
    with open(filepath) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    max_lines = len(lines)
    for k, line in enumerate(lines):
        if k >= (int(skip_header_line) + int(index_line_number)): # skipping headerlines
            data_tmp = line.split(',')
            strDate = data_tmp[0].replace("\"", "")  #  2016-02-25 14:48:36.76
        strDate = strDate.split('.')[0]  #  2016-02-25 14:48:36  
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')     # 2016-02-25 14:48:36
        ts = calendar.timegm(timestamp.timetuple())  #  1456411716  

            data_buffer = [ts] + data_tmp[1:]
            for val in data_buffer:
                if val == " ":
                    val = None
                    data_buffer.append(val)
                else:
                    continue
            print data_buffer

            cursor.execute(add_data, data_buffer)
            cnx.commit()

            with open(marker_file, "w") as f:
                f.write(" ".join([ str(item[0]), str(data_tmp[0]), str(max_lines), str(k-int(skip_header_line)+1) ]))
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

I got the following error

```
 [1456411716, ' ', '8.277527', '0.68', '0.15', '0.42', '762.0303', '4.6801\n']

 mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1265 (01000): Data 
 truncated for column 'RNO' at row 1
```

if someone had any idea how to deal with such a situation. I will really appreciate.

Comment: what line give you the error?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I got problem in this line .  data_buffer.append(float(val))    . it is the line below else:

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, but you can save as text and then create another column on db and update using the text value

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I edit my question. maybe it now more clear that where I am getting problem. instead of whole timestamp value it stop on 2016-.

Comment: why you save `strDate` instead of  `timestamp`. Also dont see you use `ts` or `ts_`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thanx for pointing those mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, if i understood your problem, you should not loop over the timestamp returned from the calendar.timegm-function.

```
ts = calendar.timegm(timestamp.timetuple())  #  1456411716  

data_buffer = []
for val in ts:
```

Slightly modified your code:

```
lines = '''
"2009-02-25 14:28:36.76",0,8.277527,0.68,0.15,0.42,762.0303,4.6801
"2009-02-25 14:28:36.8",1,8.24408,0.7,0.03,0.3,761.878,4.682412
"2009-02-25 14:29:36.88",2,8.277527,0.55,0.09,0.31,762.0018,4.680709
"2009-02-25 14:30:36.92",3,8.277527,0.47,0.2,0.31,761.8914,4.684526
"2009-02-25 14:48:36.96",4,8.277527,0.46,0.14,0.28,761.9133,4.692356
"2009-02-25 14:58:37",5,8.210632,0.42,0.09,0.35,761.9025,4.696963
"2009-02-25 14:58:37.08",6,8.277527,0.51,0.19,0.27,761.8416,4.69718
"2009-02-25 14:58:37.12",7,8.277527,0.36,0.23,0.33,761.7534,4.701172
"2009-02-25 14:58:37.16",8,8.24408,0.44,0.08,0.5,761.8087,4.700504
'''

skip_header_line = 0
index_line_number = 0

if 1:
    lines = lines.splitlines()
    for k, line in enumerate(lines):
        if k <= (int(skip_header_line) + int(index_line_number)):
            continue

        data_tmp = line.split(',')
        strDate = data_tmp[0].replace("\"", "")  #  2016-02-25 14:48:36.76
        strDate = strDate.split('.')[0]  #  2016-02-25 14:48:36
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')     # 2016-02-25 14:48:36
        ts = calendar.timegm(timestamp.timetuple())  #  1456411716  

        # rebuild list, first element is ts the others from data_tmp (excluding the datetime)
        data_buffer = [ts] + data_tmp[1:]
        print data_buffer

        # here your insert ?
```

results in this:

```
[1235572116, '0', '8.277527', '0.68', '0.15', '0.42', '762.0303', '4.6801']
[1235572116, '1', '8.24408', '0.7', '0.03', '0.3', '761.878', '4.682412']
[1235572176, '2', '8.277527', '0.55', '0.09', '0.31', '762.0018', '4.680709']
[1235572236, '3', '8.277527', '0.47', '0.2', '0.31', '761.8914', '4.684526']
[1235573316, '4', '8.277527', '0.46', '0.14', '0.28', '761.9133', '4.692356']
[1235573917, '5', '8.210632', '0.42', '0.09', '0.35', '761.9025', '4.696963']
[1235573917, '6', '8.277527', '0.51', '0.19', '0.27', '761.8416', '4.69718']
[1235573917, '7', '8.277527', '0.36', '0.23', '0.33', '761.7534', '4.701172']
[1235573917, '8', '8.24408', '0.44', '0.08', '0.5', '761.8087', '4.700504']
```

Comment: thanx for the hint.  it actually works but I got the error which I add in my question after editing.                                                                   [1456411716, '0', '8.277527', '0.68', '0.15', '0.42', '762.0303', '4.6801\n']
  I GOT similiar lines before the error. Can you please look at my edited question?. .I am really thankful to you for your hint

Comment: Adjust your skip_header_line, arent there 3 header lines ? It might helpful to debug what you are trying to insert: 'print data_buffer'

Comment: I think I am getting some problem here ...mean \n  in every line............... [1456411716, '0', '8.277527', '0.68', '0.15', '0.42', '762.0303', '4.6801\n']

Comment: Ahh, ok. Now in data_buffer all values are strings, you may need to convert to float or whatever is matching your database columns. I assume ' Data truncated' means you are trying to insert a value into the database, which may be longer than the column.

Comment: use 'data_tmp = line.strip().split(',')' to remove the '\n'

Comment: you are genius sir. thanx a lot for the help . I accept your answer because it solve my problem. .

Answer (score 0):

```
  data_buffer = []
  for val in strDate:
      if val == " ":
         val = None
         data_buffer.append(val)
      else:
         data_buffer.append(float(val))    # Got problem
```

I think should be

```
  data_buffer = []
  data_buffer.append(timestamp)
```

Comment: thanx for the hint but it dispaly the same error. ..............................................TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable